# Why my recyclerview just don't show anything?

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I'm using a recyclerview to show restaurants that are previously saved in a database, and I'm using volley to get their information, but it is not working, I suspect that is a problem with volley code, can you guys help me at this point? I will be very happy!

I've discovered that if I start another activity then I go back to home, it returns the recyclerview again, but if I change the fragment it disapears.

**Here is how the app is working for now: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p03GH.png)**

**Fragment Home code:**

```
package com.example.techtable;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Home extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private ArrayList<restaurantes> restaurantesArrayList;
    private static final String url = "https://cybersquare.dev.br/php/obterRestaurantes.php";

    TextView txterro;
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;



    public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Pedidos newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Pedidos fragment = new Pedidos();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedIntanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedIntanceState);
        
        dataInitialize();
        recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapterRestaurante myAdapter = new adapterRestaurante(getContext(),restaurantesArrayList);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void dataInitialize() {
        restaurantesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String titulo = object.getString("nome");
                            String descricao = object.getString("descricao");
                            int avaliacao = object.getInt("avaliacao");
                            int valor = object.getInt("valor");

                            String fotoResto = object.getString("fotoRestaurante");

                            restaurantesArrayList.add(new restaurantes(titulo, descricao, avaliacao, valor, fotoResto));

                        }


                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }, error -> Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);


    }
}
```

**Recyclerview adapter:**

```
package com.example.techtable;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class adapterRestaurante extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterRestaurante.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<restaurantes> restaurantesArrayList;


    public adapterRestaurante(Context context, ArrayList<restaurantes> restaurantesArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.restaurantesArrayList = restaurantesArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public adapterRestaurante.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_linha_pesquisa, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapterRestaurante.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        restaurantes restaurantes = restaurantesArrayList.get(position);
        holder.titResto.setText(restaurantes.titResto);
        holder.descResto.setText(restaurantes.descResto);
        Picasso.get().load("fotoPerfil").into(holder.fotoResto);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return restaurantesArrayList.size();
    }

    public static  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView fotoResto;

    ImageView primeiraEstrela;
    ImageView segundaEstrela;
    ImageView terceiraEstrela;

    ImageView primeiroDolar;
    ImageView segundoDolar;
    ImageView terceiroDolar;

    TextView titResto;
    TextView descResto;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titResto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titResto01);
            descResto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descResto01);
            fotoResto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotoResto01);

            primeiraEstrela = itemView.findViewById(R.id.estrela11);
            segundaEstrela = itemView.findViewById(R.id.estrela12);
            terceiraEstrela = itemView.findViewById(R.id.estrela13);

            primeiroDolar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor11);
            segundoDolar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor12);
            terceiroDolar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.valor13);
        }
    }
}
```

**Arraylist restaurantes**

```
package com.example.techtable;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class restaurantes {

    String titResto;
    String descResto;
    int avaliacaoResto;
    int valorResto;
    String fotoResto;

    public restaurantes(String titResto, String descResto, int avaliacaoResto, int valorResto, String fotoResto) {
        this.titResto = titResto;
        this.valorResto = valorResto;
        this.avaliacaoResto = avaliacaoResto;
        this.fotoResto = fotoResto;
        this.descResto = descResto;
    }

}
```

**MyViewHolder layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ConstainerResto01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/botaoresto"
        android:onClick="teste"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fotoResto01"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/botaoredondo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fotoResto01"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/estrela11"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_posticestrelacheia"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/estrela12"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_posticestrelameia"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/estrela13"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_posticestrelavazia"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/valor11"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_posticdolarcheio"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/valor12"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_posticdolarcheio"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/valor13"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_posticdolarmeia"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descResto01"
                    android:layout_width="118dp"
                    android:layout_height="49dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_thin"
                    android:text="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"
                    android:textColor="@color/cinza_medio"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titResto01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_black"
                    android:text="Restaurante 01"
                    android:textColor="@color/laranja"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment Home layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Olá usuário!"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView29"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView20" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logotechtablecolorida"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtUsuario"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="Escolha seu restaurante e faça seu pedido"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUsuario" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout8" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**JSON file:**

```
<?php 
    header('content-type: application/json');
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","cyber536_admin","mJEn@*a]0Jc*","cyber536_techtable");
    mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf-8');
    $query = "select nome, avaliacao, descricao, fotoRestaurante, valor from restaurantes;";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $json_data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $json_data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($json_data);
?>
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting error text somewhere -- maybe in a log? I don't know anything about volley -- or programming for Android, for that matter -- but if you want a good answer on here from someone who does, it will help to include as much information about the failure as possible.

Comment: oh it's because it doesn't show any error, the recyclerview simply are hidden, but I'll attach how it looks like